Replace parts of a text file using a for loop
I'm using the pylatexenc library to parse a LateX file (.tex) into nodes (tuples). For every node that matches a condition, the LateX code corresponding to said node is deleted or replaced.
How can I ensure that the different edits all happen (sequentially) to the same text, rather than producing separate versions for each loop, each with their own edit?
from pylatexenc import latexnodes, latexwalker
from pylatexenc.latexnodes import LatexNodesCollector, LatexTokenReader
from pylatexenc.latexnodes.nodes import LatexEnvironmentNode, LatexCharsNode, LatexMacroNode, LatexGroupNode, LatexNode
from pylatexenc.latexnodes.parsers import LatexGeneralNodesParser
from pylatexenc.latexwalker import LatexWalker
import re

data=(r'''
\section{Heading}\label{heading-label}
\begin{enumerate}
\def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
\item
  Pater noster qui est in caelis.
\end{enumerate}

\section{Heading 2}
\begin{enumerate}
\def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
\setcounter{enumi}{1}
\item
  Et ne nos inducat in tempore malo.\footnote{footnote}
\item
  Gratia plena dominus tecum.
\item
  Panem nostrum quotidanum da nobis hodie.
\end{enumerate}
''')

my_latex_walker = LatexWalker(data)
my_reader = LatexTokenReader(data)
parsing_state = my_latex_walker.make_parsing_state()
nodes, parsing_state_delta = my_latex_walker.parse_content(LatexGeneralNodesParser())
def traverse(node):
    #Parsing for enumerate environments with additional arguments and removing them
        if node.isNodeType(LatexEnvironmentNode) and node.environmentname == "enumerate":
            subnodes = node.nodelist
            if subnodes[0].isNodeType(LatexCharsNode)\
            and subnodes[1].macroname == "def"\
            and subnodes[2].isNodeType(LatexMacroNode)\
            and subnodes[2].macroname == "labelenumi"\
            and subnodes[3].isNodeType(LatexGroupNode):
                string_inside_environment = (subnodes.latex_verbatim())
                string_with_environment = (node.latex_verbatim())
                if subnodes[5].macroname == "setcounter":
                    to_remove =  str(subnodes[0].latex_verbatim()) + str(subnodes[1].latex_verbatim()) + str(subnodes[2].latex_verbatim()) + str(subnodes[3].latex_verbatim()) + str(subnodes[4].latex_verbatim()) + str(subnodes[5].latex_verbatim())
                else:
                    to_remove =  str(subnodes[0].latex_verbatim()) + str(subnodes[1].latex_verbatim()) + str(subnodes[2].latex_verbatim()) + str(subnodes[3].latex_verbatim()) + str(subnodes[4].latex_verbatim())

                cleaned_string = (string_inside_environment.replace(to_remove,''))


            #Parsing the cleaned up string for first level \item commands and replace by \mypara
                my_latex_walker2 = LatexWalker(cleaned_string)
                itemnodes, parsing_state_delta2 = my_latex_walker2.parse_content(LatexGeneralNodesParser())
                for itemnode in itemnodes:
                    if itemnode.isNodeType(LatexMacroNode) and itemnode.macroname == "item":
                        revamped_string = cleaned_string.replace(itemnode.latex_verbatim(), r'\mypara ')
                        result = data.replace(string_with_environment, revamped_string)

        if node.isNodeType(LatexGroupNode): #Recurse into groupnodes
            traverse(node)

for node in nodes:
    traverse(node)

print(data)


What is parse_function()?  Where does nodes  come from?  Where is traverse() actually called?  It's very hard for us to work with such incomplete code.

Ok, I added a MWE.  data now results in the original input source code.  I would like to alter the text in data several times using a for loop and then print the altered text.    Printing result  also does not give me this.

Can you give some context: (a) What do you want to change (e.g. get rid of custom enumeration styles to use a global; use "\myparam"  instead of "\item"), (b) Why do you want to change the enumerations (e.g. prepare for post-processing by a tool like Pandoc; apply "\task" from tasks package)  ?

If your previous question is related, it would help to link them in the question-body and explain their role in the overall solution?

Maybe you missed to find the exit of the long function traverse and to spot

where data goes in as input,
where data was modified,
where result came out as output.

Here is an approach to refactor (break up into functions) and follow the Command-Query Separation (CQS):
Refactored
First, the Query part:

First read the nodes read_nodes(latex)
Then iterate over the nodes and find replacements in each (old traverse function), now add_replacement_for(replacements, node)

Now the Command part:

With the found  replacement pairs, edit the latex

from pylatexenc import latexnodes
from pylatexenc.latexnodes import LatexNodesCollector, LatexTokenReader
from pylatexenc.latexnodes.nodes import LatexEnvironmentNode, LatexCharsNode, LatexMacroNode, LatexGroupNode, LatexNode
from pylatexenc.latexnodes.parsers import LatexGeneralNodesParser

input_latex = r'''
\section{Heading}\label{heading-label}
\begin{enumerate}
\def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
\item
  Pater noster qui est in caelis.
\end{enumerate}

\section{Heading 2}
\begin{enumerate}
\def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
\setcounter{enumi}{1}
\item
  Et ne nos inducat in tempore malo.\footnote{footnote}
\item
  Gratia plena dominus tecum.
\item
  Panem nostrum quotidanum da nobis hodie.
\end{enumerate}
'''

def read_nodes(latex):
    walker = LatexWalker(latex)
    # not used?
    # reader = LatexTokenReader(latex)
    parsing_state = walker.make_parsing_state()
    nodes, parsing_state_delta = walker.parse_content(LatexGeneralNodesParser())
    return nodes
    

def is_enumeration(n):
    return n.isNodeType(LatexEnvironmentNode) \
        and n.environmentname == "enumerate" \
        and n.nodelist[0].isNodeType(LatexCharsNode) \
        and n.nodelist[1].macroname == "def" \
        and n.nodelist[2].isNodeType(LatexMacroNode) \
        and n.nodelist[2].macroname == "labelenumi" \
        and n.nodelist[3].isNodeType(LatexGroupNode)


def clean_enumeration(environment_node):
    string_inside_environment = (environment_node.latex_verbatim())
    subnodes_latex = [n.latex_verbatim() for n in environment_node.nodelist]
    to_remove = ''.join(subnodes_latex[0:4])
    if environment_node.nodelist[5].macroname == "setcounter":
        to_remove += subnodes_latex[5]

    return (string_inside_environment.replace(to_remove,''))


def revamp(latex):
    walker = LatexWalker(latex)
    itemnodes, parsing_state_delta = walker.parse_content(LatexGeneralNodesParser())
    for itemnode in itemnodes:
        if itemnode.isNodeType(LatexMacroNode) and itemnode.macroname == "item":
            latex.replace(itemnode.latex_verbatim(), r'\mypara ')
    return latex
    

# traverse    
def add_replacement_for(replacements, node):
    # parsing for enumerate environments with additional arguments and removing them
    if is_enumeration(node):
        string_with_environment = (node.latex_verbatim())
        cleaned = clean_enumeration(node)
        # parsing the cleaned up string for first level \item commands and replace by \mypara
        revamped = revamp(cleaned)
        pair = (string_with_environment, revamped)
        replacements.append( pair )
    if node.isNodeType(LatexGroupNode):  # recurse into groupnode's nodelist
        for subnode in node.nodelist: 
            add_replacement_for(replacements, subnode)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    nodes = read_nodes(input_latex)

    # traverse latex nodes to find replacements
    # recursively add replacements to initial list
    replacements = []
    for node in nodes:
        add_replacement_for(replacements, node)

    # print found replacements
    print(f"Found {len(replacements)} pairs in replacements: {replacements}")
    
    # now replace
    output_latex = input_latex
    for found, by in replacements:
        output_latex = output_latex.replace(found, by)

    # print the result
    print(f"Replaced latex:\n{output_latex}")

Prints:
Found 2 pairs in replacements: [('\\begin{enumerate}\n\\def\\labelenumi{\\arabic{enumi}.}\n\\item\n  Pater noster qui est in caelis.\n\\end{enumerate}', '\\begin{enumerate}\n\\item\n  Pater noster qui est in caelis.\n\\end{enumerate}'), ('\\begin{enumerate}\n\\def\\labelenumi{\\arabic{enumi}.}\n\\setcounter{enumi}{1}\n\\item\n  Et ne nos inducat in tempore malo.\\footnote{footnote}\n\\item\n  Gratia plena dominus tecum.\n\\item\n  Panem nostrum quotidanum da nobis hodie.\n\\end{enumerate}', '\\begin{enumerate}\n\\def\\labelenumi{\\arabic{enumi}.}\n\\setcounter{enumi}{1}\n\\item\n  Et ne nos inducat in tempore malo.\\footnote{footnote}\n\\item\n  Gratia plena dominus tecum.\n\\item\n  Panem nostrum quotidanum da nobis hodie.\n\\end{enumerate}')]
Replaced latex:

\section{Heading}\label{heading-label}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
  Pater noster qui est in caelis.
\end{enumerate}

\section{Heading 2}
\begin{enumerate}
\def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
\setcounter{enumi}{1}
\item
  Et ne nos inducat in tempore malo.\footnote{footnote}
\item
  Gratia plena dominus tecum.
\item
  Panem nostrum quotidanum da nobis hodie.
\end{enumerate}

Issues with the recursion of group nodes
What about the recursion?
Is it infinite, if node of type GroupNode is recursed again and again?
Original code:
   if node.isNodeType(LatexGroupNode): #Recurse into groupnodes
        traverse(node)

Refactored by me:
    if node.isNodeType(LatexGroupNode):  # recurse into groupnode's nodelist
        for subnode in node.nodelist: 
            add_replacement_for(replacements, subnode)

The LatexGroupNode has an attribute nodelist which can be used to traverse all subnodes.

This is fantastic. So readable. Thank you!  I'm indeed running into an infinite recursion error. How can I stop recursion once all LatexGroupNodes have been processed?

@TimothyRoes To stop recursion, don't iterate over the node itself infinitely - iterate through and recurse into each subnode of LatexGroupNode.nodelist. See my update and the test output.

The correct output is produced by putting print(result) outside of the function. Including it in the function definition will loop over it, so that the output is repeated several times.
Reusing result outside the function definition produces a NameError. This can be avoided by including global result in the function definition.
